# replacing inner text of an invalid xml file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to replace inner text of the tag of an XML file. The XML file I have is not well formed so we cannot use LINQ-TO-XML. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
<conf-start ISO-8601-date="2011-05-31"><day>31</day><month>Jan</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>
```

Within the XML file I just want to replace Jan to 01.
Note : The month name can change in different files and also the

```
ISO-8601-date="2011-05-31"
```

Can change. So basically is it possible to find the expression to replace the above line in an invalid XML file.

i tried this,

```
Dim filePath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim directory1 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
    Dim split As String() = filePath.Split("\")
    Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 2)
    Dim yourXml = XDocument.Load(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml").Root

    ' Change each monthname to the number of the month
    For Each elem In yourXml...<conf-start>.<day>.<month>
        elem.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(elem.Value, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month
    Next

    ' save file
    yourXml.Save(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
```

but in some files i get errors such as xlink is an undeclared prefix and in some other files i get different errors

Comment: What makes you think that this is invalid XML?

Comment: because in our company we are provided with invalid xml to make it well formed.

Comment: But the example XML you provided *is* well formed as far as I can see

Comment: ya but when i use linq to xml, when i load the file it shows errors in the remaining lines of the file due to which replacement cant be done

Comment: Please post the code you are using to read the file and the errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Dim y = "<conf-start iso-8601-date=""2011-05-31""><day>31</day><month>Jan</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>"

   Dim Match = Regex.Match(y, "<month>([^>]*)<\/month>").Groups(1).ToString
   Regex.Replace(y, Match, DateTime.ParseExact(Match, "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month.ToString)
```

It will give you OP Like

```
<conf-start iso-8601-date="2011-05-31"><day>31</day><month>01</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>
```

Comment: yaa but the iso-date will keep on changing per different files and the date is not fixed

Comment: iso-8601-date=""2011-05-31"" but the problem is that it will not match when the above date is changed and the date here will keep on changing so as the value in <day>tag

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    ds.ReadXml("yourXmlFile.xml")
    If Not ds Is Nothing Then
        ds.Tables("conf-start").Rows(0)("month") = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("month"), "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month.ToString
        ds.WriteXml("yourXmlFile.xml")
    End If
```

Comment: month can changes repective to different files and i need to replace the month name given in the file with its respective month number..the code should read the file and replace the month in the <conf-start> tag only and replace the values accordingly.

Comment: @jigar is the xml only have one `<conf-start>` tag or maybe more

Comment: it has only one and only one <conf-start> tag plz remember that the  iso-8601-date=""2011-05-31"" the date given may keep changing in different files and so as the value of the <day> tag

Comment: did you try my code? while you only have one tag it will only check for the month tag and change it with the value you want.

Comment: but there are several month tags in the file but i want to replace only the moth tag inside <conf-start> tag